# É possível nomear um parâmetro no momento da chamada da função?

Tags: javascript, python, funções

Posso "acessar" um parâmetro especifico de uma função de JavasScript, ou seja, dar um valor para um determinado parâmetro? Como exemplo é melhor do que texto (já que não sei me explicar direito), aqui vai um:

Em Python, tendo uma função:

```py
def funcX(A="A",B="B",C="C"):
    print(A+B+C)
```

...que resultaria em:

```py
'ABC'
```

...eu posso mudar o valor de determinado parâmetro assim:

```py
funcX(C = "c")
```

...o que resulta em:

```py
'ABc'
```

Quero saber se há alguma forma de fazer o mesmo em JavaScript.
Exemplo:

```js
function funcX(A,B,C){        
    if(typeof A != 'string'){A= "A"}
    if(typeof B != 'string'){B= "B"}
    if(typeof C != 'string'){C= "C"}

    alert(A+B+C)
};
```

Resultaria em:

```js
'ABC'
```

E ai gostaria de fazer algo como:

```js
funcX(C = "c")
```

...para resultar em:

```js
'ABc'
```

Aproveitando, gostaria de fazer uma pergunta paralela (se é que isso é permitido):
Existe uma forma melhor de dar "valores padrão" para os parâmetros das funções em Javascript do que `if(typeof A != 'string'){A= "A"}`?

Como em Python `def funcX(A="A")`

*(desculpem tanta comparação, mas é que aprendi a programar em Python, e é a única referência que tenho)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A maneira usual de fazer parâmetros nomeados ou opcionais em Javascript é passar um objeto (dicionário) como parâmetro. Um exemplo famoso é a função [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#entry-examples) da biblioteca jQuery.

No seu caso ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
function funcX(kw){
    var A = kw.A || "A";
    var B = kw.B || "B";
    var C = kw.C || "C";
    console.log(A+B+C);
}

funcX({a:"oi", c:"!", b:"mundo"});
```

É bem comum usar `||` em parâmetros opcionais em JS porque o código fica bem sucinto mas se você quiser aceitar valores "falsy" como `0` ou `""` você pode fazer testes mais precisos usando typeof ou o operador `in`:

```
 var A = "A" in kw ? kw.A : "defaultA";
```

Comment: Muito bom, eu voltei aqui justamente pra comentar que acabei de descobrir que poderia usar um objeto para fazer parâmetros com "valores padrão" (descobri justamente usando JQuery, mais precisamente com jQuery Ui).
Fazendo algo como `funcX({C:'c'})`.  

Mas na verdade não descobri muito bem como funciona por dentro

Comment: Não tem muita mágica. O análogo em Python seria passar um dicionário como parâmetro ao invés de usar *keyword arguments*. Pra implementar parâmetros opcionais você pode usar o operador `in` para testar se o dicionário contém um certo campo (funciona igual a Python) ou você sair acessando os campos diretamente mesmo (em Python acessar um campo inexistente de um dicionário é um erro mas em Javascript você simplesmente obtem o valor `undefined`, que é tipo um `null` só que um pouco diferente).

Answer (score 7):

Em JavaScript tens mesmo de chamar a função passando os parâmetros todos. A função que colocaste é bem no caminho certo, se tiveres:

```
function funcX(A,B,C){        
    if(typeof A != 'string'){A= "A"}
    if(typeof B != 'string'){B= "B"}
    if(typeof C != 'string'){C= "C"}

    alert(A+B+C)
};
```

então se só queres mudar o C terias de chamar a função com `funcX(null, null, 'c');`.

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kdxerxpw/

Outra maneira de dar valores padrão seria:

```
function funcX(A,B,C){        
    A = A || 'A';
    B = B || 'B';
    C = C || 'C';

    alert(A+B+C)
};
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kdxerxpw/1/

mas acho  que como tens é melhor, mais específico.
No caso de não precisares de redefenir nenhum parâmetro podes chamar a função somente com `funcX();`

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kdxerxpw/2/

Comment: Obrigado Sergio, queria poder economizar digitação, mas infelizmente não posso passar apenas um parâmetro. Fazer o que
Pelo menos agora não to com a duvida, eu sei que não posso

Outra coisinha, vi ali que você editou meu tópico
Foi você quem colocou os Highlights?