# Predefinição nos parâmetros da função em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funções, parâmetros

É possível fazer predefinições dos parâmetros nas funções JavaScript? Algo como:

```
function teste(oi = "ola", type = 1) {
```

Como predefinir as variáveis caso elas não forem definidas?

Comment: Além da pergunta indicada no topo, ver também http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48548/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-nomear-um-par%C3%A2metro-no-momento-da-chamada-da-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Comment: Nesta outra questão, [tenho uma função `WithDefaults` que](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15387/1925) dada uma outra função F e um array A, gera outra função F' que aceita parâmetros default. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masbicudo/Ygwhy/2/)

Answer (score 4):

Isto costuma ser chamado de *default parameters*. E JavaScript não permite esta sintaxe. O melhor que pode ser feito é definir valores logo no início da função:

```
function teste(oi, type) {
    oi = (typeof(oi) === "undefined" || oi === null) ? "ola" : oi;
    type = (typeof(type) === "undefined" || oi === null) ? 1 : type;
    //continua a função aqui
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/DefaultValue.js).

Se vai usar muito isto é possível criar uma função para simplificar esta sintaxe. Algo assim:

```
function def(variable, value) {
    return (typeof(variable) === "undefined" || === null) ? value : variable;
}
```

Aí usaria assim:

```
function teste(oi, type) {
    oi = def(oi, "ola");
    type = def(type, 1);
    //continua a função aqui
```

Há uma forma experimental para ter uma sintaxe na linguagem conforme [documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters). Desta forma poderia usar da maneira como você quer. No momento só funciona no FireFox.

Answer (score 4):

Existem diversas maneiras de fazer isso, uma delas é a seguinte:

```
function foo(a, b)
{
   a = typeof a !== 'undefined' ? a : 'seu_valor_default_a';
   b = typeof b !== 'undefined' ? b : 'seu_valor_default_b';

   //Seu código
}
```

**OBS.: Reposta copiada da original feita por** [Tom Ritter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8435/tom-ritter) em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function