# Verificar se um parâmetro foi fornecido para a função

Tags: javascript, funções, parâmetros

Assumindo uma função em JavaScript com parâmetros:

```
function minhaFuncao (param1, param2, param3) {
    // fazer algo ...
}
```

E depois utilizando a mesma da seguinte forma:

```
var param1 = "bubu";

minhaVariavel = minhaFuncao (param1);
```

ou

```
var param1 = 30,
    param2 = true;

minhaFuncao (param1, param2);
```

## Pergunta

De que forma podemos verificar, dentro da função, se um parâmetro de qualquer tipo foi fornecido para evitar utilizar o mesmo ?

Exemplo com uso do parâmetro sem ter recebido o mesmo:

```js
function minhaFuncao (param1) {

  alert("BuBu diz: " + param1);
}
minhaFuncao();
```

<sup>Nota: Não interessa propriamente o tipo dos parâmetros, interessa saber se os mesmos foram recebidos para evitar problemas na lógica ou agir em conformidade.</sup>

Comment: Podem ser destes tipos ou devem ser destes tipos respectivamente? Ou eles podem ser qualquer um dos três mas não se for de outro tipo, é considerado sem parâmetro válido?

Comment: @bigown Editei para ilustrar melhor o pretendido. O tipo é indiferente para o problema em mãos.

Comment: É que não achei que fosse tão simples, é quase dup de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56710/101 que já é uma dup.

Comment: @bigown Os assuntos nas duas que referes são diferentes desta onde nos encontramos a comentar. Embora as respostas estejam bem completas e acabem por referir o solução para o problema que temos em mãos nesta pergunta, as outras não procuram saber se o parâmetro foi ou não fornecido. [Nesta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56710/223) procura definir valor por defeito, [nesta também](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15350/223). A questão é que procurando por este problema especifico não cheguei às perguntas/respostas que referiste...

Comment: Sim, claro, por isto eu disse quase. Neste caso você faz o que quiser se não receber o parâmetro, naquelas o que fazer já é especificado.

Comment: @bigown É isso! Só clarifiquei para não induzir futuros leitores a fechar como dup. São relacionadas sim, mas não são iguais ;)

Comment: A quem deu downvote, seria bom saber o motivo para melhorar o que tiver que melhorar ou remover a pergunta se a mesma não é boa para este site!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dentro de cada função podes verificar o `typeof` de cada argumento.

Se `typeof param1 == 'undefined'` então ele não foi passado, ou foi passado sem valor defenido..

Podes também verificar diretamente com:

```
if (param1 !== undefined) {
    // argumento enviado e não undefined
} else {
    // argumento não enviado ou undefined
}
```

O JavaScript disponibiliza uma array `arguments` dentro da função com todos os argumentos que foram passados à função. Podes verificar o `arguments.length` dentro da função para ter a certeza se os parametros todos foram enviados.
Sendo que não é possivel saltar parametros, ou seja fazer `minhaFuncao ('foo', , , 'bar');` o `arguments.length` vai dar a quantidade de argumentos/parametros passados à função. Se o numero de argumentos for menor que o nr de parâmetros, dá para saber quais os parametor que nem foram passados (mesmo que `undefined`)  à função.

Answer (score 4):

Se quiser verificar pelo tipo, então pode usar o operador `typeof`.

- `typeof param1 == 'string'`
- `typeof param2 == 'number'`
- `typeof param3 == 'boolean'`

```js
var div = document.getElementById("xx");

function minhaFuncao(param1, param2, param3) {
  if (typeof param1 == 'string') {
    div.innerHTML += ("param1 é string") + " ";
  }
  if (typeof param2 == 'number') {
    div.innerHTML += ("param2 é number") + " ";
  }
  if (typeof param3 == 'boolean') {
    div.innerHTML += ("param3 é boolean") + " ";
  }
  div.innerHTML += "<br/>";
}

minhaFuncao();

minhaFuncao("");

minhaFuncao("", 2);

minhaFuncao("", 2, true);

minhaFuncao("", 2, true, "extra", "extra", "extra", "extra", "extra");
```

```html
<div id="xx"></div>
```

É possível saber quais parâmetros foram passados baseando-se na contagem de parâmetros fornecidos na chamada.

Para saber quantos parâmetros foram fornecidos na chamada da função é possível usar `arguments.length`.

Assim, se `arguments.length` for 1, então sabemos que `param1` foi fornecido. Se for 2 então `param1` e `param2` foram fornecidos. Se 3, então todos os parâmetros foram fornecidos. Se for maior que 3, então a função foi chamada com mais parâmetros do que os declarados em sua assinatura.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("xx");

function minhaFuncao (param1, param2, param3) {
    div.innerHTML += "" +arguments.length + "<br/>" ;
}

minhaFuncao("");

minhaFuncao("", 2);

minhaFuncao("", 2, true);

minhaFuncao("", 2, true, "extra", "extra", "extra", "extra", "extra");
```

```html
<div id="xx"></div>
```

Comment: O meu objetivo não é propriamente saber se foram fornecidos 1, 2 ou 3 parâmetros. A ideia é apurar se um parâmetro foi fornecido para evitar tentar usar o mesmo e "rebentar" com a função. :) (se vires que a pergunta não está clara o suficiente, avisa-me para a reescrever)

Comment: Por exemplo, se foram passados 2 parâmetros, então quer dizer que o `param3` não foi passado. Se não for isso, então eu não entendi a questão.

Comment: Acho que entendi melhor... editei.

Comment: +1 pelos exemplos e métodos de verificação. Aceitei a do @Sergio por ter a solução verificando independentemente do tipo.